# Change IntelliJ Run Configuration Environment Variables with Plugin

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I am trying to build a plugin for IntelliJ that when pressing a button, it will load env vars from the web to the current Run Configuration.

I couldn't find a way to reach the current Run Configuration, let alone to edit the env vars.

When trying to create new Action all I get as a parameter is a `AnActionEvent` and I couldn't find anything useful there

```
public class HelloAction extends AnAction {

    public HelloAction() {
        super("Hello");
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(AnActionEvent event) {
        Project project = event.getProject();
    }
}
```

I would be happy for any clue here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the current run configuration, use `RunManager.getInstance(project).getSelectedConfiguration().getConfiguration()`. Then check if the returned object implements `CommonProgramRunConfigurationParameters`, and if it does, call the `setEnvs` method of this interface to change the environment variables.

Comment: is it possible to fetch all the `Run Configurations Templates` and change theirs envs? Where can I find the documentation regarding those issues? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it's possible. There is no documentation, but the code is open-source.